# How to use rackspace php-opencloud with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm trying to use the [php-opencloud library](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud) with Laravel 4 (it's my first time with it, I'm a bit intimidated...)

I have added this to my composer.json, tried a composer update, which downloaded the lib correctly, but what's next? How can I autoload it?

```
"repositories": {
    "php-opencloud": {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "rackspace/php-opencloud",
            "version": "1.4.1",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "origin/master"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the packages you install via Composer make use of autoloading:

- [Basic Usage: Autoloading<sup>*Composer Docs*</sup>](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

That is basically just including a single file in your bootstrap and you're ready to go:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

That is relative to the location where you placed your `composer.json` file.

Comment: yes but in this case, php-opencloud library is not (yet) composer friendly. So I don't know what I have to do add to get it working with laravel.

Comment: @pvledoux: php-opencloud supports composer *officially* since May 2013 and also it was a piece of cake to turn it into a composer package earlier on - so it was always composer friendly (not mentioning that it was available on packagist already so was just out of the box). See as well [Issue #22](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/issues/22) for more support information (as you know).